# Responsive Mobile Design for Gmail App

Tags: html, css

Trying to just make the code to be mobile friendly based on only **Gmail** Mobile. So no other `media queries` are needed since it doesn't work for Gmail. Please do help me as I am new and very confused by looking at the the Gmail solutions. It works just fine in desktop but not in mobile Outline `CSS` doesnt work for gmail as well. Only inline css

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container-table" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0;width:100%; max-width:800px;">
  <tr>
    <td> $container1
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0;min-width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td width="450"><div id="minicontainer1" style="padding: 5px 0 0 20px; height:80px;line-height:50%;box-sizing:border-box;">
              <p class="font1" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold; color:black;"> Name of the person </p>
              <p class="font2" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:9.5pt; color:black;"> Web Developer </p>
              <p class="font2" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:9.5pt; color:black;"> Phone number </p>
            </div>
            <div id="minicontainer2" style="  padding:0 0 0 20px; margin-top:-10px; line-height:50%;box-sizing:border-box;">
              <p class="font1 diffsize" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; color:black;"> $company </p>
              <div class="font2 diffsize" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:8pt; color:black; line-height: 12px;">
                <p> $address. </p>
                <p> Phone : <span id="special" style="color: #0000EE !important; text-decoration: underline;"> $telno </span> | Fax :<span id="special" style="color: #0000EE !important; text-decoration: underline;"> $faxno </span> </p>
              </div>
            </div></td>
          <td width="220" align="center"> $logo </td>
          <td width="110" align="center"> $imgshow </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      $royalty
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0; min-width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td><div id="minicontainer4" style="padding:15px 0 0 20px; width:92%; box-sizing:border-box;">
              <p class="font3" style=" font-family: Helvetica; font-size:6pt; font-weight:lighter; color:black; letter-spacing:0.25px; text-align:center;"> Prohibited EMail.</p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0; min-width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td width="800"><div id="minicontainer5" style="height:40px; background-color: #EBF2F0; margin-top:15px; padding:4px 0 0 70px;">
              <div id="box2" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center; width:500px; box-sizing:border-box;">
                <ul style="list-style:none; margin:5px;">
                  <li style="float:left; padding: 0 10px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size:9.5pt;color:black; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">Website : $web </li>
                  <li style="float:left; padding: 0 10px; margin-left:0px"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> <img src="email_signature/images/facebook.png"> </a> </li>
                  <li style="float:left; padding: 0 10px; margin-left:0px"> <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank"> <img src="email_signature/images/twitter.png"> </a> </li>
                  <li style="float:left; padding: 0 10px; margin-left:0px"> <a href="https://www.plus.google.com/" target="_blank"> <img src="email_signature/images/googleplus.png"> </a> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="clear" style="clear:both;"> </div>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0;min-width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td width="800"><div id="minicontainer6" style=" padding-top:5px; text-align: center; box-sizing:border-box;">
              <p class="font2" style="font-size:5.5pt; font-family: Helvetica; color:black;"> Comapny limited </p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this as it's not a direct answer but I don't have enough rep...

Since media queries aren't supported on the gmail app it's a pretty in depth problem to tackle. Using this method may involve re-building your email but this tutorial is incredibly helpful:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919